# How to write script to sort two buckets individually in elasticsearch

Tags: java, json, elasticsearch, groovy, lucene

I have two fields (ID and Name) in elastic search.

I have a requirement to search and sort data by below conditions :

Bucket 1 : Contains all records having Name value empty (Sort by ID field in ascending order)
Bucket 2 : Contains all records having Name value Present (Sort by Name field in ascending order)

then return all the records of Bucket 1 followed by Bucket 2 in one response.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you could state this a bit differently:  Get all documents, and Sort first by Name (empty first!), then by ID.

Stated that way, the solution falls out pretty easily.  Empty fields should be sorted first when sorting in ascending order anyway, so:

```
{
    "query" : {
        "match_all": {}
    },
    "sort" : [
        { "Name" : "asc" },
        { "ID" : "asc" }
    ]
}
```

Comment: But in this case Bucket 2 will be sorted by ID also and that i do not want. I want Bucket 1 will be sorted by ID field only and Bucket 2 will be sorted by name field only. In the result Bucket 1 will be followed by Bucket 2.

Comment: @Shailendra - Bucket 2 will be sorted by ID only when Name is equal.  Since you didn't specify how it should be sorted when Names are equal, I assumed this was acceptable.